# How to enable multiple ssl protocol versions in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl

So far I managed to enable either TLSv1.3 or TLSv1.2 by specifying it in *application.properties* file in resources folder.

```
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.3
```

*or*

```
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2
```

How to make TLSv1.2 and also TLSv1.3 both available?

*(TLSv1.2 is not deprecated yet and i want to create support for older browsers/software that are compatible with/implemented 1.2 only)*

Comment: Comma separated list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all properties that support multiple values (collection or array) use a comma separated list.

```
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
```

Comment: BTW this gives warning: o.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfig   : The protocol [TLSv1.2] was added to the list of protocols on the SSLHostConfig named [_default_]. Check if a +/- prefix is missing. Any clue how to fix this? [TLSv1.2] is replaced with [TLSv1.3] depedning on order.

Comment: That is a different questions which isn't going to be resolved through comments. So please formulate a new question for that.

Comment: To overcome that warning message, your property should be `server.ssl.enabled-protocols=+TLSv1.2+TLSv1.3`